# AppleScript iTunes script randomly throws error

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

So, I've been having this strange glitch where the following piece of code inexplicably throws an error, namely error -50: parameter error

Code:

```
set county to 0
tell application "iTunes"
    set name of current track to songName
    set county to 1
    set artist of current track to songArtist
    set county to 2
    set genre of current track to genreVar
    set county to 3
    set grouping of current track to aFolder2
    set county to 4
    set comment of current track to fileName
    set county to 5
end tell
set county to 6
```

I wrapped this piece of code in a try statement to catch the error and added the county variable to see where the error happened, and every time it occurred, the error happened with county = 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your script probably fails when "current track" is empty ! add an if statement to check if current track exists or not. For instance, when you just open iTunes, current track is empty.

Comment: @pbell Normally, the current track should never be able to be empty. The script opens mp3 files into iTunes one by one and only proceeds once the added mp3 file is playing, which means that it can't be empty.

Comment: Then if the  script fails before county=1, the failure is on "set name of current track to song name". Since you confirmed current track is not empty (I still strongly suggest to  test it !), then it means that you can't set/change the name of current track. is the track locked ? first log is you can get the name. if not, then back to empty track. if yes, then track is locked.